# Elegant way to run shell command from ruby script and fail on shell command error

Tags: ruby, shell, error-handling

I know something like this is possible

```
out = `echo 1`
$?.to_i == 0 or raise “Failed"
```

Yet I’m unable to merge these 2 statements, so that the output will be captured into a variable and the command will fail (also printing the captured output) if the shell command returns with error.

Preferably into a 1 lines, if possible. Something like

```
out = `echo 1` && $?.to_i == 0 or raise “Failed. Output:” + out
```

only prettier.

Comment: Look at the [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) class. It has a number of methods that will let you do what you want. In particular, `capture2` is the closest to what you're doing.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if command fails it will most probably be `stderr`, not `stdout`. `cmd` form doesn't capture `stderr`, neither does `capture2`. You may need `capture3` and no, it's not one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) class. It has a number of methods that will let you do what you want.

In particular, `capture2` is the closest to what you're doing. From the docs:

> ::capture2 captures the standard output of a command.

```
stdout_str, status = Open3.capture2([env,] cmd... [, opts])
```

Pay attention to that optional `env` parameter. Without that your called application will have no environment information so you might want to consider passing in the `ENV` hash, allowing the child to have the same environment settings as the running code. If you want to restrict what is passed you can selectively add key/value pairs to a hash, or use `ENV.dup` then `delete` selected key/value pairs.